# Object Feed Tab Default - Details Tab Instead - Chatter Feed Tracking

Tags: chatter, administration, history-tracking, chatter-feed, field-history

Does unchecking "**Enable Feed Tracking**" effectively make it so when you visit a record on (example) Account, it now defaults to the DETAILS tab **instead of** the FEED tab?

**Where**:   Setup >> Chatter >> Feed Tracking

*I am not seeing this in documentation and cannot confirm via Google searches, but would like to be sure...*  I've tested by (after changing the setting) loading various records I personally have never accessed before, and they are all now "seemingly defaulting" to the DETAILS tab (which is desired anyway).

Thank you.